# Values must be filled at least one, trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, constraints

I have persons table, three contact value, mobile, homephone, mail,

I need to trigger that: if all values are null, rollback it or throw exception, if one, two or all are filled, commit.

How its possible to do with trigger?

```
alter trigger [dbo].[PersonsContactFilter_TR] on [dbo].[Persons]
for insert
as
begin
  select Mobile, HomePhone, Mail 
  from inserted
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue that a trigger is not really needed for that purpose. You could just use a check constraint:

```
alter table [dbo].[Persons]
add constraint CheckNotAllContactAreNull
check (
    Mobile is not null
    or HomePhone is not null
    or Mail is not null
);
```

Comment: i am trying to do it with triggers, when i finish i will try with constraint too. thanks anyway

Comment: A trigger is the wrong tool for this job. Use check constraints. This is the right way to handle this.

Comment: its impossible to do with triggers? or constraints are just better way?

Comment: @lukagogrichiani: while this *can* be done with a trigger, this is not the right way to do it. Constraints are. Triggers are typically meant to handle use cases that are too complex to be managed through constraints.

Comment: @GMB thanks a lot, i understand and already did it with constraint, such a 
 better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try an exists check that throws an error:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[PersonsContactFilter_TR] on [dbo].[Persons]
for insert
as
begin
  if exists (
    select 1 
    from inserted
    where Mobile is null and HomePhone is null and Mail is null
  ) begin
    ;throw 51000, 'Mobile, HomePhone and Mail cannot all be null', 1;
  end 
end
```

Comment: incorrect syntax near THROW, expecting conversation dialog disturbing or transaction

why this error  appears?

Comment: Think it just needed the preceding `;`